# Sending serialized Objects multiple times over a Socket

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

The client sends specific Objects multiple times over a socket to the server. Code looks like this:

```
public void send(Operation operation, Object o){
    try{
    out.writeObject(operation);
    if (o != null) out.writeObject(o);
    out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't write to OutputStream");
    }   
}
```

In the Object is a HashMap from Integer to Integer, thats altering very often.
The Server accepts the Message with:

```
User newUser = (User) oin.readObject();
```

The first time everything works well, the newUser Objects contains of the new received Object.
But after the second, third, ... execution, the newUser Object always reads the old Object (the HashMap contains the old Values from the first communication).
What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either call `reset()` regularly to stop the cache of objects building up, preventing you from seeing changes to those objects, or you need to use `writeUnshared()`

I would consider calling `reset()` before `flush()` each time.

Comment: okay, thank you very much. I feel really stupid right now, because i read about this solution over and over again, but it wasn't working. The problem is, that i was using reset on the InputStream of the Server, which was always spitting out error messages of course.